# Changing value of a an object of Integer class

Tags: java

How to change value of a an object of Integer class ex: here I have declared the values of objects x and y to 5 and 6 respectively and I want to swap the value stored in the objects i.e x.intValue() should be 6 and y.intValue() should be 5. Please help.

```
class second{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(In1.a);
        Integer x = new Integer(5);
        Integer y = new Integer(6);
        System.out.println(x.equals(y));
        System.out.println(x.intValue());

    }
}
```

Comment: *Note*: "the value stored in the objects" cannot be changed since `Integer` instances are immutable; *Note2*: don't use `new Integer(int)` it's  deprecated since Java 9

Comment: Thank you for telling that. I thought we can change the value stored in Integer object. But isn't there any alternative to change the value using objects?

Comment: you can create an own class, or (better?) use `AtomicInteger` as already [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60263475/changing-value-of-a-an-object-of-integer-class?noredirect=1#comment106595955_60263505) by Murat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a different answer without using a temporary variable

```
Integer x = 10; 
Integer y = 5; 
x = x + y; 
y = x - y;  //y contains 10
x = x - y;  //x contains 5
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to do it with the help of a function which will pass the Integer objects by reference. Is it possible ?

Comment: What is your inference from trying that out in a function(Integer x, Integer y)?

Comment: I wanted to make a function which is similar to that as in C like passing the objects by reference to the function and then later using them. Is that even possible in Java ?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Integer temp = x;
x = y;
y = temp;
```

1 ) Have the value of x in a temporary variable

2 ) Assign value of y to x

3 ) Assign value of temp to y

In this way, your values of x and y will get swapped.

Comment: You could explain that an `Integer` is immutable. Moreover he could use an `AtomicInteger` to change the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third variable.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Integer a = new Integer(6);
    Integer b = new Integer(3);
    Integer temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```